# Android JellyBean stock keyboard capitalizes first letter of word before question mark

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, stock-android

On my Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 running Android JellyBean 4.1.2, when I add a question mark after a word, the first letter of that word gets capitalized. Do you know why this happens and how it can be Solved? See the last Sentence? It's happened there too.

Comment: It happens because that common English syntax... a question mark signals the end of a sentence so the net work will have a capital letter

Comment: Sorry, I meant before the question mark...

Comment: hmmm does it do it after you have entered the question mark then, i.e its lower case to start with?

Comment: Yes. It's lower case. Add the question mark and it's upper case. See the words solved and sentence in my question.

Answer (score 0):

All I can see are lower case letters. It might be a bug with  your Samsung keyboard software. You could try updating your os if it is the case or you could try other apps for writing like SwiftKey for example.

Comment: See the words solved and sentence before the question marks...

Comment: Oh, I see, I was looking at the last letter not the first. If it is a bug on your Samsung Keys software then it should work fine with SwiftKey. Try installing the app just for the sake of testing this. It's free and small so it shouldn't take more than a minute or two.